# Java regular expression find substring

Tags: java, regex, substring

I'm trying to find a specific word into a string in Java. I developed a function aims to return the found string. THis is what I wrotte for now:

```
public static String getValueByregexExpr (String str, String regexExpr) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile (regexExpr, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher1 = regex.matcher (str);
    if (matcher1.find ()) {
        if (matcher1.groupCount () != 0 && matcher1.group (1) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= matcher1.groupCount (); i++) {
                System.out.println ("matcher " + i + " for regex " + regexExpr + "= " + matcher1.group (i));
            }
            return matcher1.group (1);
        }
        return regexExpr;
    }
    return null;
}
```

My issue is the following, I wish to find a regex able to fill in the group(1) with the word I'm looking for. But for now this code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String str = "HELLO_WORLD_123456 TEst";

    System.out.println ("First test");
    String regex1 = ".*WORLD.*";
    String matchedString = Util.getValueByregexExpr (str, regex1);
    //Here, I want to obtain matchedString = WORLD
    if (matchedString == null) {
        System.out.println ("matchedString null");
    } else if (matchedString.equals (regex1)) {
        System.out.println ("String found but empty group(1)");
    } else {
        System.out.println ("Result : " + matchedString);
    }

    //Here, I want to obtain matchedString = WORLD_123456
    System.out.println ("\nSecond test");
    String regex2 = "WORLD_([^_]+)";
    matchedString = Util.getValueByregexExpr (str, regex2);
    if (matchedString == null) {
        System.out.println ("regex " + regex2 + " matchedString null");
    } else if (matchedString == regex2) {
        System.out.println ("regex " + regex2 + " String found but empty group(1)");
    } else {
        System.out.println ("regex " + regex2 + " Result : " + matchedString);
    }

}
```

Give me the output:

```
First test:
regex .*WORLD.* String found but empty group(1)

Second test:
matcher 0 for regex WORLD_([^_]+)= WORLD_123456
matcher 1 for regex WORLD_([^_]+)= 123456
regex WORLD_([^_]+) Result : 123456
```

First, is there any regular expression whitch can returns:
 - WORLD for the first test
 - WORLD_123456 for the second test

Second, I thought at the begining that every result will be set into group(1) as long as you have only one result. But I'm obviously wrong given test 2 result. Could someone give me more information about it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla: The second regex `"(WORLD_[^_]+)"` will return `WORLD_123456 TEst`.

Comment: Do this. `String regex1 = ".*(WORLD).*";` and `String regex2 = "(WORLD_[^_\\s]+)";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the first one, just add the capturing group:

```
String regex1 = ".*(WORLD).*";
```

To fix the second, add whitespace to the character class:

```
String regex2 = "(WORLD_[^_\\s]+)";
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/j3E2Fr)

The main reason your first part of code was not working as expected is the missing capturing groups that your `getValueByregexExpr` is checking for. 
The second one returned the part of stirng captured with the `([^_]+)` regex part.

Comment: I didn't realize the importance of the "()". Using your regex it is working now, and all the information I need are set into group(1).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In regex, everything inside `()` becomes a group.

Correct you `regex`.

```
String regex1 = ".*(WORLD).*";
```

```
String regex2 = "(WORLD_[^_\\s]+)";
```